# VScode : How I can install package to global python interpreter(3.10.5)?

Tags: python, package, interpreter

[image]

hi! please check the image first.

I tried to install package to global python interpreter.
Surely, I selected my interpreter as python 3.10.5, not conda environment.

However when I tried to install the package, it was installed to conda environment interpreter, so I can't use the package on my global python interpreter, not conda.

How I can solve this problem?

I wanna install new package to python 3.10.5 interpreter, not conda 3.9.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to install them via the built-in terminal and not via vscode.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a different problem: the module cv2 is found, but the `cv2.show()` command is not. I don't think that command exists in OpenCV, do you mean `cv2.imshow()`?